# Segue from SKScene to storyboard creating instances of old scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, segue, skscene

Here is my storyboard showing a segue to a `UINavigationController`:

[image]

I fade out my game scene and call this segue from my `SKScene` like so:

```
mainVC?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tySeg", sender: nil)
```

The nav controller moves a `UIViewController` on top of the game scene, as expected. But during the transition, I can see two new instances of the `SKScene` popping up in the background before the transition finishes and they are covered up by the new view controller. A print statement in my scene's `didMove(to view:)` method confirms that an `SKScene` object is appearing twice.

I can't figure out why my `SKScene` subclass is automatically being called twice after it triggers a segue. I also tried presenting the view controller like so but had the same issue:

```
mainVC?.present(navVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

I have a cludgy workaround in mind but I'd rather understand what is causing this to happen so I can prevent it. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I suspect the reason has something to do with a passage from [this Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH14-SW1):

> When presenting a view controller using the
>   `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` style, UIKit normally removes the views
>   of the underlying view controller after the transition animations
>   finish. You can prevent the removal of those views by specifying the
>   `UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen` style instead. You might use that
>   style when the presented view controller has transparent areas that
>   let underlying content show through.
>
> When using one of the full-screen presentation styles, the view
>   controller that initiates the presentation must itself cover the
>   entire screen. If the presenting view controller does not cover the
>   screen, UIKit walks up the view controller hierarchy until it finds
>   one that does. If it can’t find an intermediate view controller that
>   fills the screen, UIKit uses the root view controller of the window.

You can see in my screenshot that `GameViewController` is my initial view controller. This is where I am calling the segue from. Like the doc says, maybe UIKit is removing the underlying content (the `SKView` that is presenting my game scene) when the segue is called. But I am using a full-screen presentation style, and UIKit requires that the scene's view controller must cover the screen. Since it was removed by UIKit, then UIKit goes up the view hierarchy and finds `GameViewController` which it calls to display.

I'm making a lot of assumptions, but seems like that might explain why my game scene is being recreated twice (or once... I had different results in my testing) while it calls a segue and waits for the transition to finish.

Also, I noticed that if I change the segue I'm using from `Show` to `Present Modally, Over Full Screen`, then the issue does not occur. That seems to support my guess.

Comment: To clarify, I can avoid this issue by using an `Over Full Screen` segue. But the real question is why the `SKScene` is being automatically instantiated during the segue's transition. The scene's VC is being automatically called during the transition... but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after our conversation it turns out that it uses the same instance of GameViewController.
So in your case you just workaround it. It's happening because your second view controller somehow not covering the entire screen (or it has opacity), and the system layout again the GameViewController. As you quoted:

> When using one of the full-screen presentation styles, the view
>   controller that initiates the presentation must itself cover the
>   entire screen. If the presenting view controller does not cover the
>   screen, UIKit walks up the view controller hierarchy until it finds
>   one that does. If it can’t find an intermediate view controller that
>   fills the screen, UIKit uses the root view controller of the window.

For others i'll keep some of the old answer:

When you `segue` to a view controller you always creates a new instance. **(So if you want to reuse the instance, don't use segues!)**

When you `present`, you always shows it modally.

When you `show` you move to another view controller.

Comment: Thanks, those tips are helpful for understanding the VC creation. But the main problem is why the underlying `SKScene` is being instantiated when I don't want it to.

Comment: Try to print some debug logs in your game view controller to understand what is happening, you may try to use the navigation controller delegate too.. Post some data and I'll try to help

Comment: I did some of that earlier and updated my question with what I suspect is the answer, but I'm hoping someone can confirm it. When the segue fires, GVC's `viewWillDisappear` method is called. Then immediately after (while the segue is still in progress), GVC's `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method is called, indicating that a new GVC is being created (and I can see a new game scene appear before the segue finishes). I suspect GVC is being called automatically by UIKit, as suggested by the Apple doc quoted in my updated question.

Comment: I don't sure it's created twice. I think it's uses the same instance of GVC. Please create a static int var (with 0 value) in GVC, then increment the var in every time any one of GVC's constructor is being called. You can debug with breakpoints if you don't want to add the var

Comment: Just did it in the GVC's `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and the var was incremented. This tells me that it is the same instance, as you said. Now I'm thinking that maybe the reason GVC is being called twice is because the segue is asking the view controller of the underlying scene to lay out its subviews again. That might explain why `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is being called twice.

Comment: Exactly, according to the docs you quoted it's because the new view controller is not full screen, but that strange to say... You can find a programmatic workaround for this

Comment: My workaround was to programmatically hide the scene's contents but that was not the best way. The easiest way was to simply pick a different style of segue. Thanks for your help! If you want to update your answer I can accept it as the solution. Or if you prefer I could edit it myself to add the Apple quote & explanation :)